# Firebase Functions onCreate trigger Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Trying to deploy a function with OnCreate triggered for a database but it keeps returning me this error. Here's the simple code and the error response:

Just not able to figure out why the match undefined error?

Versions of Modules:

```
nodejs: Version 8.11.3
Function : deployed with node 8 runtime version. 
"firebase": "^5.3.0"
"firebase-admin": "^5.12.1"
"firebase-functions": "^1.1.0"
"typescript": "^2.5.3"
```

Code:

```
import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
exports.functionName = functions.database.ref('/user/{uid}/email').onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log(snap.val());
});
```

Question Update: This is the latest and most updated code. I am trying to get the details of the object newly added.

Error there is a new element added to user in firebase database:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at resourceToInstanceAndPath (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/database.js:154:26)
    at dataConstructor (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/database.js:122:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:89:32)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36)
    at /worker/worker.js:728:24
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: The following should work, see my answer: `exports.dbCreate = functions.database.ref('/user/{uid}/email').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const createdData = snap.val(); console.log(createdData);
});`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the "old" syntax of Cloud Functions (prior to version 1.0.0 of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions) with `onCreate((event) => {})` and the version of the SDK in your project is version 1.1.0.

You should change the syntax to

```
.onCreate((snap, context) => {})
```

as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database)

Comment: Hey @Renaud Tarnec, I did try using, but resulted in the same error.

Comment: What exact console logs are you using. Can you please **add** to your question the exact code you are trying and the error you get?

Comment: I have other functions , which seem to be working fine, but this one seems to be an issue. Everytime , a new value is added to firebase database, the function does trigger, but always returns with the same error.

Comment: Is there another part of your code where you call a property called `match`?

Comment: Nope absolutely nothing apart from this one file , and that’s exactly what got me , because there is nothing that I do which matches and returns undefined

Comment: What may happen is that there is a global problem with Could Functions at this time: there is another StackOverflow question with a similar problem and it seems not working despite everything **seems** correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052392/unable-to-send-notifications-using-firebase-functions-after-update. The Firebase dashboard seems all green https://status.firebase.google.com/ but maybe there is a problem. You may contact the support: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/?category=troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, when i deployed i had this warning:

> ⚠  functions: You must have a firebase-functions version that is at
>   least 2.0.0. Please run npm i --save firebase-functions@latest in the
>   functions folder.

after i installed the last firebase-functions version it worked.

So my solution was:

> npm i --save firebase-functions@latest

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem as well, and i believe its related to using node8 in the firebase functions. at least thats the last major change.

Comment: Yes George, Thank you. Had to face a few integration and migration issues because of Node 6 vs Node 8. Now that firebase allows you to specify the node engine, it helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the changes you had to make to get this working. I'm currently using firebase-functions v2.x and nodejs6, but I'm still getting the error mentioned in the OP's title.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that my Cloud Function trigger event type (write) and my call to `firebase.database.ref('...').onChange(...)` were mismatched. Once I switched the call to `firebase.database.ref('...').onWrite(...)`, everything worked great!

Kind of a stupid mistake on my part. Hope this is helpful to someone else!