# Unable to send notifications using firebase functions after update

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

So Today I updated the firebase cli and after that deployed a new function. Although the firebase log shows that notifications has been sent to this many tokens, no notification occurs. An error shows in the log

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

I searched for answers in stack overflow but nothing helped.
Also I would like to add that before it was showing some different error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of null

and now suddenly it is showing function returned undefined.

Not sure what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


function token_send(admin,title_input,body_input,getBody,getDeviceTokensPromise,change){

  // Only edit data when it is first created.
  if (change.before.val()) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Exit when the data is deleted.
  if (!change.after.val()) {
    return 0;
  }



return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise,getBody]).then(results => {
  const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
  const notify=results[1];

  if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
    return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
  }
  console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
  var contentAlert = change.after.val();

  // Notification details.
  const payload = {
    'data': {
      'title': title_input,
      'body': body_input

    }

  };


const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());



  // Send notifications to all tokens.
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
     console.log("content alert",contentAlert);
    // For each message check if there was an error.
    const tokensToRemove = [];
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
      const error = result.error;

      if (error) {
        console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
        // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
            error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
          tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
        }
      }
    });

    return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
  });

});
}




exports.sendNotificationCouncil = functions.database.ref(`path/Post/{pushId}`).onWrite((change,context) => {
const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Token/token_no`).once('value');
  const getBody=admin.database().ref(`/Post`).once('value');
  var title_input='You have new Post';
  var contentAlert = change.after.val();
  var body_input=contentAlert.description; //showing error here
  token_send(admin,title_input,body_input,getBody,getDeviceTokensPromise,change);
  });
```

[image: Screenshot of the console]

Answer (score 0):

You should return the promise (returned by `token_send()`) in the `sendNotificationCouncil` Cloud Function, as follows:

```
exports.sendNotificationCouncil = functions.database.ref(`path/Post/{pushId}`).onWrite((change,context) => {
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/Token/token_no`).once('value');
  const getBody=admin.database().ref(`/Post`).once('value');
  var title_input='You have new Post';
  var contentAlert = change.after.val();
  var body_input=contentAlert.description; //showing error here

  return token_send(admin,title_input,body_input,getBody,getDeviceTokensPromise,change);
});
```

Note that it is also a best practice to catch the errors in your Function and in this case return `false`.

Comment: It's still the same. It is also now showing the TypeError message. Not sure what is going on! Firebase keeps changing stuffs after every update which is frustrating.

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(contentAlert)`? Is it null? What may happen is that there is a global problem with Could Functions at this time: there is another StackOverflow question with a similar problem and it seems not working despite everything **seems** correct. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052200/firebase-functions-oncreate-trigger-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-matc

Comment: Console.log(contentAlert) is not null. It is giving a value. Is there any way to tackle this or the only way is to wait for things to get right?

Comment: So, if `contentAlert` is not null, has `contentAlert` has a property named `description`? Can you show what `console.log(contentAlert)` outputs?

Comment: yes it has the description property. you can check the screenshot of console in the edited question.

Comment: Sorry to insist, could you please show the **exact** code of the console.log() that generates the line in the log

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178930/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-yaha-kaha).

Comment: I have edited the code.   It is right below `console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);`

Comment: And what if you put the `console.log()` directly in the `exports.sendNotificationCouncil` Function and not in `token_send`